# permission error while making ugc video post on linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api, permission-denied

I am trying to create video post on linkedin with new ugc endpoint

there are two steps to create this type of post

1). Upload video asset on linkedin server (done)
2). make post request to ugc endpoint with request body

I have successfully uploaded the video but getting authentication error for ugc post request. error is

```
{
    "message": "urn:li:developerApplication:<id1> does not have permission to create ugc posts with author: li:member:<id2>",
    "status": 401
}
```

I am passing the request body as suggested in the linkedin api docs.

```
{
  "author": "urn:li:person:<id>",
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "specificContent": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
      "media": [
        {
          "title": {
            "attributes": [],
            "text": "Sample Video Create"
          },
          "description": {
            "attributes": [],
            "text": "Sample Description"
          },
          "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:<asset_id>",
          "thumbnails": [],
          "status": "READY"
        }
      ],
      "shareCommentary": {
        "attributes": [],
        "text": "Some share text"
      },
      "shareMediaCategory": "VIDEO"
    }
  },
  "visibility": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
  },
  "targetAudience": {
    "targetedEntities": [
      {
        "locations": [
          "urn:li:country:us"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please suggest how I can solve this problem. From error message it seems like I am not providing some permission. But I am not sure where I am making mistake.

Comment: I encountered today the same issue. Did you guys manage to find a solution?

Comment: Same here. I'm getting this error message:

{
    "message": "com.linkedin.publishing.util.common.ResponseException: urn:li:developerApplication:5212106 does not have permission to create ugc posts",
    "status": 401
}

Comment: same discussion on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878672/permission-error-while-making-ugc-video-post-on-linkedin

Answer (score 5):

This is the response I got from the [LinkedIn Developer Support](https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us):

"Hi Ervin,

Creating video UGC posts is currently a whitelisted feature. There is currently hold on whitelisting new apps for video.

You may continue to create UGC posts that are not video though.

I'll put this on hold until I have more information on when we can whitelist apps again.

Best,
Alex"

Comment: Is the restriction still exist, i am also facing the same issue

Comment: Yes. I pinged Alex from LinkedIn two weeks ago and he said that there's still no update yet.

Comment: I am still facing this issue in 2024, any updates here?