# UGC post video on LinkedIn to personal page

Tags: linkedin-api, ugc

I want to share a video with the UGC post API : https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/ads/create-and-manage-video

It works fine if I share a video to a company page. But it doesn't work with a personal page. I have this error:

> urn:li:developerApplication:XXXXX does not have permission to create ugc posts with author: urn:li:member:XXXXXXXX

I have set these authorizations in my LinkedIn app:  `w_share, rw_organisation_admin, rw_compagny_admin, w_member_social, rw_organisation`

Could you please help me? Many thanks.

Comment: same problem, I think ugcpost is in closed beta

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you do not have the right permissions.

> Your app needs to authorize an access token with the **rw_ads** permission to create and manage video ads. If your application needs read only access please use **r_ads**. If you are using legacy permissions, please refer to this page for requesting legacy permissions.

this quote i found on the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

So I asked this on the LinkedIn Developer Support, and apparently this is a whitelisted functionality. Only a few apps can create video UGC posts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934631/7844946

Comment: Please, provide context for links, check the StackOverflow documentation [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I actually wanted to post this as a comment, but because I don't have enough reputation for comments, I posted it as an answer. This is also a duplicate question, but because the original question does not have an accepted answer, I couldn't flag it. The link is simply my full answer to the original / most complete question.