# linkedIn how to apply ugcPosts permisson

Tags: linkedin-api

I called the ugcPosts api. it returns "developerApplication:4861615 does not have permission to create ugc posts". How can I get the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Only a few apps have been whitelisted to create video UGC posts and LinkedIn currently is not accepting new apps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934631/7844946