# How to upload video and post using linkedin API?

Tags: rest, api, video, linkedin-api

I am developing an app that allows the user to upload the video and publish across several social sites like  (Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin).For that i am looking to use the Linkedin upload video Api. I search a lot but couldn't find any relevant documentation that could help me. Anyone have a chance to work on this. Any help would appreciate ?
Note : I am using the php laravel framework

Comment: Please see this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923208/upload-video-using-linkedin-v2-api/55948455#55948455

Answer (score 0):

You can upload videos to LinkedIn, at least in theory, using their new [UGC Post API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#create-ugc-posts).

I say in theory because creating video UGC Posts is currently a whitelisted feature. If you follow the steps in the documentation above, you will get stuck at the very last step as it will throw this error:

> com.linkedin.publishing.util.common.ResponseException:
>   urn:li:developerApplication:APP_ID does not have permission to create
>   ugc posts

After contacting [LinkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934631/7844946), they confirmed that while you can create other types of UGC Posts (status updates, link attachments and photos), videos are for the moment not supported and there is currently a hold on whitelisting new apps for video.